# Как пункты <select> <option>.....</select> обернуть в input type='checkbox', чтобы все работало?

Tags: javascript, form, input, checkbox

Вообще не понимаю, как правильно все элементы обернуть в чекбоксы и написать перехват кликов на них, подсчитывая количество выбранных(именно на js).

```
<form name="selectForm">
<p>
<label for="list">Выберите строчки:</label>
<select type = 'checkbox' id="list" name="line" multiple>
<option value='A' selected>A</option>
<option value='B'>B</option>
<option value='C'>C</option>
<option value='D'>D</option>
<option value='E'>E</option>
</i>
</select>
<p> <input id="btn" type="button" value="Сколько выбрано?" /></p>
</form>

<script>
function Quantiny(selectLine) {
var numberSelected = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < selectLine.options.length; i++) {
if (selectLine.options[i].selected) {
numberSelected++;
}
}
return numberSelected;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
alert('Выбрано элементов: ' + Quantiny(document.selectForm.list))
});
</script>
```

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет это - http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/multiple

Comment: А это что за хвост `</i>`?

Comment: ошибка, должен быть </p>

Comment: эта ошибка вообще не объясняет ситуацию  и как ее решить, ну, серьезно

Comment: атрибут multiple указан, как мне поможет статья об этом атрибуте загадка

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id="form" name="selectForm">
  <legend for="list">Выберите строчки:</legend>

  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" checked>
    <label for="a">A</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b">
    <label for="b">B</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c">
    <label for="c">C</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="d" name="d">
    <label for="d">D</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="e" name="e">
    <label for="e">E</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <button id="btn" type="button">Сколько выбрано?</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
function Quantiny() {
  let inputsNode = document.querySelectorAll('#form>.form-item>input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  console.log(`Кол-во выбранных: ${inputsNode.length}`)
}

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', Quantiny);
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое